# Parsing JSON and displaying in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, laravel, api

Feedback App

```
    String url = "http://www.dohagarage.com/api/v1/sample";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new 
   JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String naame = hit.getString("question");

        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(naame));
                        } mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

This is the code I used to show the questions using json in a `RecyclerView`. I want show the options in a radio button.

Comment: what is the exact problem in your code? can you tell in brief?

Comment: I cant see anything when running the app.The questions are not displaying.

Comment: Are you getting the api response. Is the parsing correct or any exception is being thrown. Did u check this

Comment: My emulator not working on system I am actually building the apk and testing it on mobile so i coudnt get error informations.

Comment: when I used another api it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code to better understand but i think you didn't set Layout Manager to RecyclerView

Comment: http://www.dohagarage.com/api/v1/sample    - this is the api. I cant display the options in my app.

Comment: the questions are showing but the options are not displaying and I also don,t know how to send the radiobutton value to server

Comment: JSON response value looks like this                                                             
      {"data":[{"id":167,"question":"Is our staff professional, friendly & caring?","options":["Very satisfied","satisfied","Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Very dissatisfied"],"button_type":"1","option_count":"5"}.                                           
                 How can I show it in a recyler view?